# Jersey does not see my MessageBodyReader

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to use jersey with my own json MessageBodyReader/MessageBodyWriter (as I am not use @XmlRootElement... annotations on my domain classes).

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public final class MyGsonMessageBodyHandler implements MessageBodyWriter<Object>, MessageBodyReader<Object> {
...
}
```

Jersey uses this class as messagebodywriter (as it stops at breakpoint in the implemented method writeTo). Hovewer it does not see this class as messagebodyreader (and even when I break up this class to the separate implementations of the messagebodyreader/messagebodywriter it still refuses to use my messagebodyreader).

The testing code looks as follows (jersey-grizzly):

```
final Greeting greeting = resource.path("/greeting")
            .queryParam("name", name)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get(Greeting.class);
```

The error I got looks as follows:

```
A message body reader for Java class test.Greeting, and Java type class test.Greeting, and MIME media type application/json was not found
```

I'm wondering what kind of magic is required for writing own MessageBodyReader?

Answer (score 9):

After a while I found a root cause of the issue. My implementation of MessageBodyReader/Writer is OK (and I it works fine with RESTlet), but IF YOU USE **JerseyTest**, DO NOT FORGET TO ADD YOUR MessageBodyReader/Writer to it's ClientConfig:

```
/**
 * Creates custom REST client config which is mandatory since we don't use any JSON providers.
 * @return Jersey Client Config with the required classes to read/write in(out)coming data.
 */
private static ClientConfig createClientConfig() {
    final ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    config.getClasses().add(GsonMessageBodyHandler.class);
    config.getClasses().add(GsonAwareContextResolver.class);
    return config;
}

/**
 * Public ctor
 * @throws com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.TestContainerException On error
 */
public MyRestExposureTest() throws TestContainerException {
    super(new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("my.rest.package")
            .clientConfig(createClientConfig())
            .contextPath("/")
            .build());
}
```

Otherwise your client code would be unable to read/write your POJOs.

Comment: I'm using jersey 1.17 and this does not work for me. The client config is never evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I'm using and it's working (currently with Jersey 1.8).

```
public static Client createMyClient() {
    ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
    cc.getClasses().add(MyProviderClass1.class);
    cc.getClasses().add(MyProviderClass2.class);
    cc.getClasses().add(MyProviderClass3.class);
    return Client.create(cc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's your case, but the common mistake is incorrect implementation of `isReadable` method.

Did you implemented it?
Do you stop there, when debugging?
Does it return true?

Answer (score 0):

After trying Alex' solution, this finally worked for me:

```
public IntegrationTest() throws TestContainerException {
    super(new LowLevelAppDescriptor.Builder(createResourceConfig())
                  .build());
}

private static ResourceConfig createResourceConfig() {
    ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.github.joschi.jersey.security.smime");
    rc.getSingletons().add(new EnvelopedWriter());
    rc.getSingletons().add(new SignedWriter());
    return rc;
}
```